# Automotive Pulse Doppler Maximum unambiguous range?

Tags: rf, radar

I am trying to calculate the maximum unambiguous range for FMCW automotive radar.

In automotive, the pulse repetition rate (Tp) is [typically](https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/us/solutions/automotive/auto/automotive-media-center/automotive-radar-webinar_229442.html) 50 - 60ms.  My equation is as follows:

[image: Maximum unambiguous range]

where c is the speed of light.  This becomes

[image]

Have I done the above correctly?  7 million metres seems wrong.  Is it different as automotive is using FMCW?

Looking [here](http://www.radartutorial.eu/02.basics/Frequency%20Modulated%20Continuous%20Wave%20Radar.en.html)

> For example, a given radar with a linear frequency shift with a
>   duration of 1 ms, can provide a maximum unambiguous range of less than
>   150 km theoretically. This value results from the remaining
>   necessarily overlap of the transmission signal with the echo signal
>   (see Figure 1) to get enough time for measuring a difference
>   frequency. Most this range can never be achieved due to low power of
>   the transmitter. Thus always remains enough time for a measurement of
>   the difference frequency.

This suggests my calculation is correct but for FMCW the chirp duration is used (in the example 1ms), as answered by Neil_UK

Comment: What is the Tp ? The range depends on the frequency of the pulse signal.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong formula or units. http://wx.db.erau.edu/faculty/mullerb/Wx365/Doppler_formulas/doppler_formulas.pdf

Comment: Why does 7e6 meters sound wrong ? I think it makes sense as that is the time (50 ms) it takes for light to travel 7e6 meters. You'd need a target 7e6 / 2 meters away to interfere with the next pulse which comes 50 ms later. It means the pulses rep. rate could be much faster than 50 ms before it affects the unamb. range.

Comment: @Bort Your link is for a Doppler type radar. This is not a Doppler type radar as that can only measure speed differences, not distance.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The title of this question states "doppler".

Comment: @Bort Good point, then OP can explain why his radar is a Doppler radar. Also for a Doppler radar it is not the **range** that is unambiguous but the **speed**.

Comment: @Foxrider83 Tp is the pulse repetition rate added to question.

Comment: @Bort here is a typical doppler range map https://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/phased_product/win64/FMCWExample_03.png

Comment: What lateral resolution must you achieve? The sidelobes will blur the distance resolution, as later-arriving energy at the OLD frequency enters the correlator/mixer.

Comment: *here is a typical doppler range map* Perhaps you're thinking that **range** and **unambiguous range** are the same. They're not ! The unambiguous range is the range that you can **purely theoretically** measure unambiguously, assuming you can measure all reflections and all signals, there's no noise for example. The **range** is the actual distance which is usable with this radar. It is limited by transmit power, noise etc. You can only have an unamb. range problem if the unamb. range is smaller that the range.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie that was in response to Borgs insistence that range could not be found with a doppler type radar.  If you know the time differential between transmission and reception, it should be possible to get the range. Nice explanation, "You can only have an unamb. range problem if the unamb. range is smaller that the range"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how the radar is working. If it times the difference between transmission and reception of the pulse, then the correct unambiguous range is given by taking 50mS as the time of flight, and doing the appropriate thing with \$c\$, which gives you 7500km.

However, it's unlikely that is how it's working. It's more likely to be using a higher rate of modulation within the pulse. In that case, you need to take the repetition rate of the actual modulation used to sense the distance.

Comment: The carrier wave is 76.5GHz.  That would mean the equation becomes (299792458*(1/(76.5*10^9)))/2
= 0.00195942783006535948  That definitely doesn't seem right.

Comment: @SeanJ no, it's not right, you want the modulation rate, not the carrier

Comment: do you mean the Chirp duration (FMCW)?

Comment: The max fundamental range will be given by the receiver bandwidth and the chirp rate, the next alias range will be given by chirp rep rate.